# React data router - pass context to loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a JWT-based API. It rotates the tokens on every response. I have a custom provider that manages this.

I'm trying to figure out how I would use React Router v6.4 data router with this setup. Specifically, I'd like to use the `loader` / `action` functions for getting the data, but those don't support `useContext` and I'm not sure how to pass that in.

I'd like `dashboardLoader` to call the API with the current set of tokens as headers that `AuthContext` is managing for me.

The goal is to have the `loader` function fetch some data to display on the dashboard and to use the `get()` call from the `AuthProvider`.

My current alternative is to just do it inside the `Dashboard` component but would like to see how to do this with a loader.

The relevant files:

```
// App.js
import "./App.css";

import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";

import Dashboard, { loader as dashboardLoader } from "./dashboard";
import AuthProvider from "./AuthProvider";
import axios from "axios";

function newApiClient() {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
}

const api = newApiClient();

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (<h1>Welcome</h1>),
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    element: (
      <AuthProvider apiClient={api}>
        <Dashboard />
      </AuthProvider>
    ),
    loader: dashboardLoader,
  },
]);
```

```
// AuthProvider
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({
  login: (email, password) => {},
  isLoggedIn: () => {},
  get: async () => {},
  post: async () => {},
});

export function AuthProvider(props) {
  const [authData, setAuthData] = useState({
    client: props.apiClient,
    accessToken: "",
  });

  async function login(email, password, callback) {
    try {
      const reqData = { email: email, password: password };
      await post("/auth/sign_in", reqData);

      callback();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      throw e;
    }
  }

  function isLoggedIn() {
    return authData.accessToken === "";
  }

  async function updateTokens(headers) {
    setAuthData((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        accessToken: headers["access-token"],
      };
    });
  }

  async function get(path) {
    try {
      const response = await authData.client.get(path, {
        headers: { "access-token": authData.accessToken },
      });
      await updateTokens(response.headers);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  async function post(path, data) {
    try {
      const response = await authData.client.post(path, data, {
        headers: { "access-token": authData.accessToken },
      });
      await updateTokens(response.headers);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      // TODO
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  const context = {
    login: login,
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
    get: get,
    post: post,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={context}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
// Dashboard
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "./AuthProvider";

export function loader() {
  // TODO use auth context to call the API
  // For example:
  // const response = await auth.get("/my-data");
  // return response.data;
}

export default function Dashboard() {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  return <h1>Dashboard Stuff</h1>;
}
```

Comment: Is `dashboardLoader` referencing *some* "global" axios "instance" by any chance? The `AuthProvider` could be rendered higher in the ReactTree and set these headers on the axios instance the app is using. Does this make sense? If not, can you edit your post to include a more complete [mcve] for all the relevant code you are using between creating the Data Router and the loader function and component?

Comment: Right now, I have the `axios` instance on the `AuthProvider`. I tried adding a request and a response interceptor for the `axios` client, but couldn't figure out how to pass in the updated tokens. Let me extract the code into something more cohesive

Comment: Updated with the example code

Comment: This a such a common usage and I was facing with the same problem. I'm wondering why the authors don't cover this in their documentations or examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the axios instance as you are, but you'll tweak the `AuthProvider` to add request and response interceptors to handle the token and header. You'll pass a reference to the `apiClient` to the `dashboardLoader` loader function as well.

AuthProvider

Store the access token in a React ref and directly consume/reference the passed `apiClient` instead of storing it in local component state (*a React anti-pattern*). Add a `useEffect` hook to add the request and response interceptors to maintain the `accessTokenRef` value.

```
export function AuthProvider({ apiClient }) {
  const accessTokenRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestInterceptor = apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        // Attach current access token ref value to outgoing request headers
        config.headers["access-token"] = accessTokenRef.current;
        return config;
      },
    );

    const responseInterceptor = apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
        // Cache new token from incoming response headers
        accessTokenRef.current = response.headers["access-token"];
        return response;
      },
    );

    // Return cleanup function to remove interceptors if apiClient updates
    return () => {
      apiClient.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
      apiClient.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
    };
  }, [apiClient]);

  async function login(email, password, callback) {
    try {
      const reqData = { email, password };
      await apiClient.post("/auth/sign_in", reqData);

      callback();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      throw e;
    }
  }

  function isLoggedIn() {
    return accessTokenRef.current === "";
  }

  const context = {
    login,
    isLoggedIn,
    get: apiClient.get,
    post: apiClient.post,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={context}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Dashboard

Note here that `loader` is a [curried function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), e.g. a function that consumes a single argument and returns another function. This is to consume and close over in callback scope the instance of the `apiClient`.

```
export const loader = (apiClient) => ({ params, request }) {
  // Use passed apiClient to call the API
  // For example:
  // const response = await apiClient.get("/my-data");
  // return response.data;
}
```

App.js

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";
import Dashboard, { loader as dashboardLoader } from "./dashboard";
import AuthProvider from "./AuthProvider";

function newApiClient() {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
}

const apiClient = newApiClient();

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (<h1>Welcome</h1>),
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    element: (
      <AuthProvider apiClient={apiClient}> // <-- pass apiClient
        <Dashboard />
      </AuthProvider>
    ),
    loader: dashboardLoader(apiClient), // <-- pass apiClient
  },
]);
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you for putting it together! Can you recommend any resources on the antipattern of useRef vs useState?

Comment: Nvm, figured it out.

Comment: Having a problem with the loader, keep getting `handler is not a function`. Here's the short code sample: https://gist.github.com/misham/892ae5620948a63cbb7bac3e6c1d7f4f

Any suggestions?

Comment: @MishaM I think it should be `loader: loader(apiClient)`. You invoke your loader function and pass in the `apiClient`, and the `fetcher` function is returned as the loader function for the route. Maybe it's easier to see if you wrote it like this: `const loader = (apiClient) => ({ request, params }) => apiClient.get("/screening_tools");`.

Comment: It looks like with this approach the first request is sent with no interceptors added, as it takes some time to add them.

Comment: this is flawed approach, because loader runs way before element is rendered therefore authProvider registers interceptors AFTER loader query. You probably need to lift AuthProvider to higher route, but anyway this looks like too complicated and I am thinking of not using loaders at all